# Adding parallax effect to Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, parallax

I have a Wordpress website with an existing theme and content.
In one page I have a div with a video background and a text in the foreground.
I want to add a parallax effect by some jQuery code.
I can use Id's or classes to both of them if needed.
Can someone advice by a reference to  code or to a relevant tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

This is available in w3schools.com

```
<style>
.parallax { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");

    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 500px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<!-- Container element -->
<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Comment: Thx but you refer to a Jpeg and wrote that I use a video background

Answer (score 0):

This website is your answer : 
http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/parallax_sections.html

Try checking their examples and implement them in your website. Make sure you are using the related IDs and Classes properly.